# gitlab-runner: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock with custom container

Tags: docker, gitlab, continuous-integration

I a gitlab project with a CI/CD pipeline and my own gitlab-runner instance to run CI/CD jobs. Everything has been working fine until now.

I'm experimenting in creating a custom container image, with all my dependencies and setup,  to run CI/CD jobs to try to cut down pipeline time and ever since that sometimes my jobs fail with:

```
ERROR: Job failed (system failure): Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running? (docker.go:646:120s)
```

Most of the time, if I click **Retry** the job succeeds. I don't really have much experience with Docker and containers but it seems to me that, when it fails, it has trouble starting the custom container image. The job output stays a long time like

```
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
Using docker image sha256:<hash> for registry.gitlab.com/<username>/<project>/buildimage:latest with digest registry.gitlab.com/<username>/<project>/buildimage@sha256:<hash> ...
```

I've never had problems before I started using my custom image. Maybe something's wrong with it or my runner isn't properly configured...

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: Can you share your runner configuration? Also what is the execution environment for your _runner_? Kubernetes? Docker? EC2?

Comment: It's a docker executor. This is the config: https://pastebin.com/fPMTqMBg

Comment: I understand it's a docker executor, but where are you hosting/running the _runner_ itself? For example, are you using the [gitlab-runner docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/gitlab/gitlab-runner) on kubernetes, just installing the runner on EC2, locally on your desktop or ? Are you possibly running multiple runners on the same underlying host? -- One thing I'm wondering is if you are running in a shared environment where the host docker socket may be accessed concurrently or if there is potential for disk I/O contention. It sounds like an I/O issue.

Comment: It's running on an LXC container. As far as the runner is concerned (I think) it's as if it is running on bare metal. Don't really know any info on the underlying infrastructure. But, until now, it was working fine.